# angular universal + @angular/flex-layout cannot work well on first rendering

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-flex-layout

I am on a ssr project with angular universal , and use flex-layout to handle media css issuses.

I found this [issuse](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/guides/SSR.md#:%7E:text=Using%20Flex%20Layout%20with%20Server%2DSide%20Rendering%20(SSR),-Introduction&text=In%20the%20browser%2C%20Flex%20Layout,CSS%20styles%20inline%20as%20necessary.)  , and imported FlexLayoutServerModule into my app-server-module as it suggest. it worked but not perfect.
the screen is gonna be like reflow after flashing as width comes from whatever 900px to the normal width which is a bad experience.
this is the first paint of my app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouRmy.png)

and this is the pic of 2s after after ssr, the client side rendering which is normal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBy4i.png)

I expect the first paint could be the final result.

here is my code of customized BREAKPOINTS

```
 function updateBreakpoints(bp: BreakPoint) {
  switch (bp.alias) {
    case 'sm':
      bp.mediaQuery = 'screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1165.98px)';
      break;
    case 'md':
      bp.mediaQuery = 'screen and (min-width: 1166px) and (max-width: 1439.98px)';
      break;
    case 'lg':
      bp.mediaQuery = 'screen and (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 4999.98px)';
      break;
  }
  return bp;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [FlexLayoutModule],
  exports: [FlexLayoutModule],
  providers: [
    // register a Custom BREAKPOINT Provider
    {
      provide: BREAKPOINTS,
      useFactory: function customizeBreakPoints() {
        return DEFAULT_BREAKPOINTS.map(updateBreakpoints);
      }
    }
  ]
})
export class CustomBreakpointsModule {}
```

here is my code of app-server-module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [AppModule, ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule, FlexLayoutServerModule, CookieBackendModule.forRoot()],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

what should I do? appreciate for your help

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: not yet, we stopped the project,so that's it